# Adsense for dynamically generated pages

Tags: google, google-adsense

On my website, I allow users to create their own forums.

I use the same template to create the forum page, so according to my understanding thus far of Adsense, it is this template that will be modified to include Adsense ad unit snippets.

The urls for the forums are dynamic, and look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/somepath/forum-a.html  (for forum A)
http://www.example.com/somepath/forum-b.html  (for forum B)
```

However, I would like to be able to differentiate revenues from forum A from revenues from forum B etc. Is this possible to do this partitioning (or 'channeling' I suppose is the correct word) using Adsense, and if yes, what are the steps required in doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just use the "channels" feature of adsense. Go to "Adsense setup" then "Channels".

Answer (score 1):

Easiest with AdSense URL channels https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/126138